# Как импортировать теги, id и текст из HTML в таблицу?

Tags: python, pandas, requests, bs4

```
    import bs4
    import pandas as pd
    
    url_code = '''
    <div class="tabledata">
        <table>
            <caption>
                    <big>type1</big>
            </caption>
                <tr>
                <select>
                    <option value="101">o1</option>
                    <option value="102">o2</option>
                </select>
                </tr>
                <tr id="101_1">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Test1(1)</td>
                </tr>
            <tr id="101_2">
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Test1(2)</td>
                </tr>
            <tr id="102_1">
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Test2(1)</td>
                <tr id="102_2">
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>Test2(2)</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    '''
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url_code, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.select_one('.tabledata')
   
    #Создаем каждый столбец
    values = [tag['value'] for tag in soup.select('option[value]')]
    ids = [tag['id'] for tag in soup.select('tr[id]')]
    tds = soup.find_all('td')
    
    #Создаем список строк
    currencies = []
    
    for i in range(0, len(tds)):
        row = [values[i].get_text(),
               ids[i].get_text(),
               tds[i].get_text()]
        currencies.append(row)
    
    #import to xlsx
    df = pd.DataFrame(currencies,
                          columns=['values','ids','tds'])
    
    df.to_excel('out.xlsx', index=False)
```

Как сохранить данные в таблицу в таком виде:

```
value   ids tds
o1  101_1   Test1(1)
o1  101_2   Test1(2)
o2  102_1   Test2(1)
o2  102_2   Test2(2)
```

Или в таком виде:

```
ids tds
101_1   Test1(1)
101_2   Test1(2)
102_1   Test2(1)
102_2   Test2(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменил исходный код работая вставляя теги при помощи bs4 которые при парсинге станут столбцами.

```
import bs4
import pandas

url_code = '''
<html><head></head><body>
<div class="tabledata">
    <table>
        <caption>
                <big>type1</big>
        </caption>
            <tr>
            <select>
                <option value="101">o1</option>
                <option value="102">o2</option>
            </select>
            </tr>
            <tr id="101_1">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Test1(1)</td>
            </tr>
        <tr id="101_2">
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Test1(2)</td>
            </tr>
        <tr id="102_1">
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Test2(1)</td>
            <tr id="102_2">
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Test2(2)</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body></html>'''

#########изменяем хтмл для парсинга
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url_code, 'lxml')
r=soup.find('select').children
seldict={}
for it in r:
    if it.string==None or it.string=='\n':
        continue
    seldict[str(it.attrs['value'])]=str(it.string)
print(seldict)

r=soup.find('table').children
for it in r:
    if not isinstance(it,bs4.element.Tag):
        continue

    if it.name != 'tr' or not it.has_attr('id'):
        continue
    tag=soup.new_tag("td")
    tag.string=it.attrs['id']
    it.insert(0,tag)

    rem=it.attrs['id'][:it.attrs['id'].find('_')]
    tag=soup.new_tag("td")
    tag.string=seldict[rem]
    it.insert(0,tag)



#парсим
df=pandas.read_html(str(soup))
df = df[0].dropna(axis=0, thresh=4)
#приводим вв нужный вид
df=df.drop(['Unnamed: 2'],axis=1)
df=df.rename({'Unnamed: 1':'ids','Unnamed: 0':'value','Unnamed: 3':'tds'},axis=1)

print(df)
'''
  value    ids       tds
0    o1  101_1  Test1(1)
1    o1  101_2  Test1(2)
2    o2  102_1  Test2(1)
3    o2  102_2  Test2(2)
'''
df.to_excel('out.xlsx', index=False)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!